# How can I automatically save workspace variables in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio

I recently installed Visual Studio Code 2019 to write some python scripts for ESRI products. I cannot figure out how to automatically save workspace variables, like other IDE's do, such as Spyder.

Basically, I would like to be able to run my code to create some variables, but then be able to run only parts of the code where the variables are referenced, without having to redefine them every time.